# How to make the user login for an offline web app?

Tags: jquery, html, web-applications, local-storage, web-sql

I am building an offline web app targeting iPhone and other mobile devices. Is there any way we can keep the user authentication saved using WebSql local storage?

So when you open the web app while it's offline, I want Either user to be logged in already or the user should be able to log in.

Comment: Interesting question, it means you'll have to store user credentials locally which is not very secure. Wonder if there is any secure way or best practices of achieving this.

Comment: Just something to think about - if checking the credentials is, by definition, done on the client in javascript, it would be trivial for someone to emulate/bypass authentication by fiddling js properties in the application. Then suppose, for example, client-side data was synced to the server when you're back online, it could cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, this is how you could do it:

When logging in (online):

- Authenticate against the server, if it's correct, store the username and a hashed password (for example using [Crypto JS](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#SHA-2)) in the WebSql database.
- If the account already exist in the local database, generate a new hash anyway in case the user has changed his password since last login.

When logging in (offline):

- Authenticate against the local database.

This will, of course, require users to log in using the online version at least once before logging in locally. This is how for example Windows 8 does it when somebody tries to log in to their Microsoft account while disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to store or use client state data ([keychain in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) also in [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html)), but for web app perspective, you don't have to do anything. You don't have to do anything because if you can it is not secure. After login, server will set [HTTP only cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie) that live for some days or weeks. During these time, request [with credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials) to the server is always authenticated by the browser. You can request login email or whatever from the server. For additional security purpose server may request [XSRF token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation%3a_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern). In that case  save it in localStorage. Loosing this token means not much.

This is the safest ways and it is also used by mobile clients including internet banking through WebView. Using browser for authentication is safest and easiest because there is a lot of weak points such as credentials storage, checking correct ssl certificates, encryption, etc. With webview, everything is taken care of by the browser.

If you are interested how these server codes are, I had explanation with [Appengine cross domain authentication server code](http://dev.yathit.com/auth/gae-login-server.html).